# Error in def_main(), excecute takes 1 positional argument, but 2 was given

Tags: python

```
import shlex
import os
os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = 'Dev'
import subprocess, socket, time, struct

def execute_command(cmd):
        f = open(log.name, "w")
        try:
            subprocess.Popen(cmd, 0, f, f) 
        except WindowsError:
            cmd[0] = cmd[0] + ".com"
            subprocess.Popen(cmd, 0, f, f) #work-around
        rc = process.wait()
        if rc != 0:
            print("Error: failed to execute command:", cmd)
            print(error)
        return result

def main():
        execute_command(["tree", "C:\\"], "treelog.txt")
        return
```

Comment: `def_main():` appears to be a typo. You probably mean `def main():` If you're going to be programming, you're going to need to improve your attention to detail.

Comment: Also, please format your code correctly. This is unreadable.

Comment: Can you show the version where you pass only one argument to `execute_command`? That passing two arguments is an error is obvious.

Comment: I only changed def main(), like this: excecute_command(["tree"], "treelog.txt") return

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear, and I'm suprised you need any explanation: you defined a function `execute_command(cmd)` that takes a single argument (`cmd`), then call it with two arguments.

There are quite a few other problems in your code but since you didn't ever bothered formatting your code and writing a real question (copy/pasting par of an error message as title doesn't count as "a real question"), I won't bother pointing them either.